# При попытке загрузки библиотеки discord.py на pyhton 3.8 выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

решил сделать бота для Дискорд в PyCharm, однако при попытке загрузки библиотеки красный шрифтом выдает вот это:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\pythonproject16\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'd:\pythonproject16\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\73B5~1\
AppData\Local\Temp\tmpptvsgnao'
         cwd: C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-30ynhgbl\aiohttp
    Complete output (24 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-6rckrctz\aiohttp.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-6rckrctz\aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-6rckrctz\aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-6rckrctz\aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-6rckrctz\aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-6rckrctz\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-6rckrctz\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
    warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-6rckrctz\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-6rckrctz\aiohttp.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\pythonproject16\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'd:\pythonproject16\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_
for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\73B5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpptvsgnao' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел похожий вопрос с ответом на него. Ответ звучит так:
Сначала `pip install wheel`, затем (но не обязательно) `python setup.py bdist_wheel`
Это решило мне проблему